# How to best get results from 3 different tables based on ID matches in Laravel.

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Trying to get products AND variants for a particular supplier. 
I can get the products easy enough, but can't figure out how to best get to the variants with matching product_id and send it to the view.
Variants.product_id matches with Product.ID

This works (getting products for the supplier)

```
 public function suppliers($id) {

    $supplier = Supplier::orderby('company_name', 'ASC')->find($id);
    $products = Supplier::find($id)->products;

    $data = [];
    $data['supplier'] = $supplier;
    $data['products'] = $products;

    return view('admin.purchasing.supplier-details', $data);
}
```

I've tried this to get the variants also without luck.

Controller:

```
    public function suppliers($id) {

    $supplier = Supplier::orderby('company_name', 'ASC')->find($id);
    $products = Supplier::find($id)->products;
    $variants = array();
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $product_id = $product->id;
        $variants[] = Variant::find($product_id);
    }
    $data = [];
    $data['supplier'] = $supplier;
    $data['products'] = $products;
    $data['variants'] = $variants;
    return view('admin.purchasing.supplier-details', $data);
}
```

View:

```
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $product['title'] }}</td>
            @foreach($variants as $variant)
                @if($variant->product_id == $product['id'])
                    <td>${{ $variant->price }}</td>   
                @else
                    <td>not set</td>
                @endif
            @endforeach    
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , you should have relation set on your models to make this work

like this For exemple :

**Supplier.php**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

**Product.php**

```
 public function variants()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Variant');
}
public function Supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supplier'); //in case you have only one supplier for each product change this to belongsto
}
```

**Variant.php**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product'); //not sure if this should be manytomany or one to many , it deppends on what you did
    }
```

anyway now you can do this

**Controller**

```
public function suppliers($id) {

    $Data = Supplier::where('id',$id)->orderby('company_name', 'ASC')->with('products.variants')->first(); //you will get the supplier with all products associated to him with variants foreach product

    return view('admin.purchasing.supplier-details')->with('Data',$Data); // now you just loop the $supplierwithproducts->products to get results (dd the variable to check output)

    }
```

**View**

```
{{ $Data->name }} // supplier name since Supplier model was the starting point
@foreach($Data->products as $product) //loop all products related to that supplier
  {{ $product->name }} //shows product name (depends on you database columns
    @foreach($product->variants as $variant) // loops all variants in the current product
      {{ $variant->name }} // shows variants
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you copy and paste this code it might not work ,but this will give you an idea how you should handle relations in laravel (levrage eloquent relations)

Check this for more informations

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

[Laracasts Defining Relationships With Eloquent](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/8)

[Laracasts Updating Records and Eager Loading](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10)

Comment: legend!! tried for hours to get this, and your method is so clean and simple. love it. cheers. @achraf